# .JS not working on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm working on my first Chrome extension to help me on my job.
Well, I have a HTML file as the extension pop-up and a .JS file to do all the magic. When I run the HTML in the browser, it works fine (it has to autocomplete the keywords are being typed) but when I run it as a Chrome extension it does not work at all.
Any idea?

JSON file

```
{
  "name": "Autocompleter",
  "version": "0",
  "description": "It completes!",

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "project with jquery",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "home.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "awesomplete.js" ],

    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="awesomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="awesomplete.css" />
</head>

<body>

<section id="multiple-values">
<input data-list="Brazil, Argentina, Uruguai, Paraguai, Nova Zelândia, Canadá" data-multiple data-minchars="1" /></label>

    <pre class="language-javascript"><code><script>new Awesomplete('input[data-multiple]', {
    filter: function(text, input) {
        return Awesomplete.FILTER_CONTAINS(text, input.match(/[^,]*$/)[0]);
    },

    replace: function(text) {
        var before = this.input.value.match(/^.+,\s*|/)[0];
        this.input.value = before + text + ", ";
    }
});</script></code></pre>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

.JS file

```
(function () {

var _ = function (input, o) {
    var me = this;

    // Setup

    this.isOpened = false;

    this.input = $(input);
    this.input.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
    this.input.setAttribute("aria-autocomplete", "list");

    o = o || {};

    configure(this, {
        minChars: 2,
        maxItems: 10,
        autoFirst: false,
        data: _.DATA,
        filter: _.FILTER_CONTAINS,
        sort: _.SORT_BYLENGTH,
        item: _.ITEM,
        replace: _.REPLACE
    }, o);

    this.index = -1;

    // Create necessary elements

    this.container = $.create("div", {
        className: "awesomplete",
        around: input
    });

    this.ul = $.create("ul", {
        hidden: "hidden",
        inside: this.container
    });

    this.status = $.create("span", {
        className: "visually-hidden",
        role: "status",
        "aria-live": "assertive",
        "aria-relevant": "additions",
        inside: this.container
    });

    // Bind events

    $.bind(this.input, {
        "input": this.evaluate.bind(this),
        "blur": this.close.bind(this, { reason: "blur" }),
        "keydown": function(evt) {
            var c = evt.keyCode;

            // If the dropdown `ul` is in view, then act on keydown for the following keys:
            // Enter / Esc / Up / Down
            if(me.opened) {
                if (c === 13 && me.selected) { // Enter
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    me.select();
                }
                else if (c === 27) { // Esc
                    me.close({ reason: "esc" });
                }
                else if (c === 38 || c === 40) { // Down/Up arrow
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    me[c === 38? "previous" : "next"]();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $.bind(this.input.form, {"submit": this.close.bind(this, { reason: "submit" })});

    $.bind(this.ul, {"mousedown": function(evt) {
        var li = evt.target;

        if (li !== this) {

            while (li && !/li/i.test(li.nodeName)) {
                li = li.parentNode;
            }

            if (li && evt.button === 0) {  // Only select on left click
                evt.preventDefault();
                me.select(li, evt.target);
            }
        }
    }});

    if (this.input.hasAttribute("list")) {
        this.list = "#" + this.input.getAttribute("list");
        this.input.removeAttribute("list");
    }
    else {
        this.list = this.input.getAttribute("data-list") || o.list || [];
    }

    _.all.push(this);
};

_.prototype = {
    set list(list) {
        if (Array.isArray(list)) {
            this._list = list;
        }
        else if (typeof list === "string" && list.indexOf(",") > -1) {
                this._list = list.split(/\s*,\s*/);
        }
        else { // Element or CSS selector
            list = $(list);

            if (list && list.children) {
                var items = [];
                slice.apply(list.children).forEach(function (el) {
                    if (!el.disabled) {
                        var text = el.textContent.trim();
                        var value = el.value || text;
                        var label = el.label || text;
                        if (value !== "") {
                            items.push({ label: label, value: value });
                        }
                    }
                });
                this._list = items;
            }
        }

        if (document.activeElement === this.input) {
            this.evaluate();
        }
    },

    get selected() {
        return this.index > -1;
    },

    get opened() {
        return this.isOpened;
    },

    close: function (o) {
        if (!this.opened) {
            return;
        }

        this.ul.setAttribute("hidden", "");
        this.isOpened = false;
        this.index = -1;

        $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-close", o || {});
    },

    open: function () {
        this.ul.removeAttribute("hidden");
        this.isOpened = true;

        if (this.autoFirst && this.index === -1) {
            this.goto(0);
        }

        $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-open");
    },

    next: function () {
        var count = this.ul.children.length;
        this.goto(this.index < count - 1 ? this.index + 1 : (count ? 0 : -1) );
    },

    previous: function () {
        var count = this.ul.children.length;
        var pos = this.index - 1;

        this.goto(this.selected && pos !== -1 ? pos : count - 1);
    },

    // Should not be used, highlights specific item without any checks!
    goto: function (i) {
        var lis = this.ul.children;

        if (this.selected) {
            lis[this.index].setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
        }

        this.index = i;

        if (i > -1 && lis.length > 0) {
            lis[i].setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
            this.status.textContent = lis[i].textContent;

            $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-highlight", {
                text: this.suggestions[this.index]
            });
        }
    },

    select: function (selected, origin) {
        if (selected) {
            this.index = $.siblingIndex(selected);
        } else {
            selected = this.ul.children[this.index];
        }

        if (selected) {
            var suggestion = this.suggestions[this.index];

            var allowed = $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-select", {
                text: suggestion,
                origin: origin || selected
            });

            if (allowed) {
                this.replace(suggestion);
                this.close({ reason: "select" });
                $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-selectcomplete", {
                    text: suggestion
                });
            }
        }
    },

    evaluate: function() {
        var me = this;
        var value = this.input.value;

        if (value.length >= this.minChars && this._list.length > 0) {
            this.index = -1;
            // Populate list with options that match
            this.ul.innerHTML = "";

            this.suggestions = this._list
                .map(function(item) {
                    return new Suggestion(me.data(item, value));
                })
                .filter(function(item) {
                    return me.filter(item, value);
                })
                .sort(this.sort)
                .slice(0, this.maxItems);

            this.suggestions.forEach(function(text) {
                    me.ul.appendChild(me.item(text, value));
                });

            if (this.ul.children.length === 0) {
                this.close({ reason: "nomatches" });
            } else {
                this.open();
            }
        }
        else {
            this.close({ reason: "nomatches" });
        }
    }
};

// Static methods/properties

_.all = [];

_.FILTER_CONTAINS = function (text, input) {
    return RegExp($.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

_.FILTER_STARTSWITH = function (text, input) {
    return RegExp("^" + $.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

_.SORT_BYLENGTH = function (a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
        return a.length - b.length;
    }

    return a < b? -1 : 1;
};

_.ITEM = function (text, input) {
    var html = input === '' ? text : text.replace(RegExp($.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "gi"), "<mark>$&</mark>");
    return $.create("li", {
        innerHTML: html,
        "aria-selected": "false"
    });
};

_.REPLACE = function (text) {
    this.input.value = text.value;
};

_.DATA = function (item/*, input*/) { return item; };

// Private functions

function Suggestion(data) {
    var o = Array.isArray(data)
      ? { label: data[0], value: data[1] }
      : typeof data === "object" && "label" in data && "value" in data ? data : { label: data, value: data };

    this.label = o.label || o.value;
    this.value = o.value;
}
Object.defineProperty(Suggestion.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype), "length", {
    get: function() { return this.label.length; }
});
Suggestion.prototype.toString = Suggestion.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return "" + this.label;
};

function configure(instance, properties, o) {
    for (var i in properties) {
        var initial = properties[i],
            attrValue = instance.input.getAttribute("data-" + i.toLowerCase());

        if (typeof initial === "number") {
            instance[i] = parseInt(attrValue);
        }
        else if (initial === false) { // Boolean options must be false by default anyway
            instance[i] = attrValue !== null;
        }
        else if (initial instanceof Function) {
            instance[i] = null;
        }
        else {
            instance[i] = attrValue;
        }

        if (!instance[i] && instance[i] !== 0) {
            instance[i] = (i in o)? o[i] : initial;
        }
    }
}

// Helpers

var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

function $(expr, con) {
    return typeof expr === "string"? (con || document).querySelector(expr) : expr || null;
}

function $$(expr, con) {
    return slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
}

$.create = function(tag, o) {
    var element = document.createElement(tag);

    for (var i in o) {
        var val = o[i];

        if (i === "inside") {
            $(val).appendChild(element);
        }
        else if (i === "around") {
            var ref = $(val);
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(element, ref);
            element.appendChild(ref);
        }
        else if (i in element) {
            element[i] = val;
        }
        else {
            element.setAttribute(i, val);
        }
    }

    return element;
};

$.bind = function(element, o) {
    if (element) {
        for (var event in o) {
            var callback = o[event];

            event.split(/\s+/).forEach(function (event) {
                element.addEventListener(event, callback);
            });
        }
    }
};

$.fire = function(target, type, properties) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

    evt.initEvent(type, true, true );

    for (var j in properties) {
        evt[j] = properties[j];
    }

    return target.dispatchEvent(evt);
};

$.regExpEscape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
};

$.siblingIndex = function (el) {
    /* eslint-disable no-cond-assign */
    for (var i = 0; el = el.previousElementSibling; i++);
    return i;
};

// Initialization

function init() {
    $$("input.awesomplete").forEach(function (input) {
        new _(input);
    });
}

// Are we in a browser? Check for Document constructor
if (typeof Document !== "undefined") {
    // DOM already loaded?
    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
        init();
    }
    else {
        // Wait for it
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
    }
}

_.$ = $;
_.$$ = $$;

// Make sure to export Awesomplete on self when in a browser
if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
    self.Awesomplete = _;
}

// Expose Awesomplete as a CJS module
if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = _;
}

return _;

}());
```

Prints:
Working
[image]
Not working (as a Chrome Extension)
[image]

Comment: Firstly, you are using `$$("input.awesomplete")`, but you didn't attach `awesomplete` class to that input in `popup.html`. Secondly, you need to create `.js` file for the second script, you cannot execute it inline.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did not get what you meant by "you cannot execute it inline". I do have a .js file.